# The named parameter 'value' isn't defined?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am encountering an issue in my Flutter code where I am using the DropDown widget, and I keep getting the error message "named parameter 'value' isn't defined." I believe this error is related to the onChanged callback of the DropDown widget. How can I resolve this issue?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dropdown/flutter_dropdown.dart';

class Language {
  final String code;
  final String name;

  Language({required this.code, required this.name});
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Text-to-Speech Example',
      home: TextToSpeechScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TextToSpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextToSpeechScreenState createState() => _TextToSpeechScreenState();
}

class _TextToSpeechScreenState extends State<TextToSpeechScreen> {
  final FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
  Language selectedLanguage = Language(code: 'en-US', name: 'English (United States)'); // Default language is English
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  // Define a list of languages
  List<Language> languages = [
    Language(code: 'en-US', name: 'English (United States)'),
    Language(code: 'es-ES', name: 'Spanish (Spain)'),
    Language(code: 'fr-FR', name: 'French (France)'),
    Language(code: 'de-DE', name: 'German (Germany)'),
    // Add more languages as needed
  ];

  // Function to speak the entered text
  Future<void> speakText() async {
    await flutterTts.setLanguage(selectedLanguage.code);
    await flutterTts.setPitch(1.0); // Adjust the pitch if needed
    await flutterTts.speak(textEditingController.text);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textEditingController.dispose();
    flutterTts.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text-to-Speech Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Language selection dropdown
              DropDown<Language>(
                items: languages,
                hint: Text('Select Language'),
                onChanged: (Language? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedLanguage = value!;
                  });
                },
                selectedValue: selectedLanguage, // Use selectedValue instead of value
                // Customize how the dropdown items are displayed
                displayItem: (Language item) => item.name, // Use displayItem instead of itemAsString
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              // Text input field
              TextField(
                controller: textEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter text to speak',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              // Speak button
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: speakText,
                child: Text('Speak Text'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have already tried mostly everything that came up to me.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what we are suppose to do here? The code is not formatted correctly, and the answer, is at line 132-133 I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The `flutter_dropdown` package does not have the parameter `value` and `itemAsString`. You should do one of the below:

```
 DropDown<Language>(
            items: languages,
            hint: Text('Select Language'),
            onChanged: (Language? value) {
              if(value != null) setState(() {
                selectedLanguage = value!;
              });
            },
            selectedValue: selectedLanguage,
            // Customize how the dropdown items are displayed
            displayItem: (Language item) => item.name,
          ),
```

or:

```
DropDown<Language>(
            items: languages,
            hint: Text('Select Language'),
            onChanged: (Language? value) {
              if(value != null) setState(() {
                selectedLanguage = value!;
              });
            },
            selectedValue: selectedLanguage,
            customWidgets: languages.map((language) => Text(language.name),
            isExpanded: true,
          ),
```